# ¿Cómo hace un AlertDialog con 2 controles? Xamarin Android

Tags: alertdialog, xamarin.android

Tengo un AlertDialog, quisiera poder poner un botón y un EditText, éste es mi código y resultado:

```
            EditText et = new EditText(this);
            Button btn = new Button(this);
            AlertDialog.Builder ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

            ad.SetTitle(parametroBorrado);

            ad.SetView(et);
            ad.SetIcon(Android.Resource.Drawable.SymContactCard);
            //ad.SetView(btn);
            btn.Click += Btn_Click;
            ad.Show();
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo agregar un botón, abajo del EditText, porque cuando ingreso

```
ad.SetView(btn);
```

Se sobre pone al EditText

Comment: no puedes usar el `PositiveButton` para esa tarea?

Comment: Cierto, no había visto que existía PositiveButton, gracias ;), estoy aprendiendo a usar AndroidXamarin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya resolvi con la ayuda de L.Ronquillo, usando PositiveButton

```
 private void LstCatalogos_ItemLongClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemLongClickEventArgs e)
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        EditText et = new EditText(this);
        alert.SetIcon(Android.Resource.Drawable.StatSysUploadDone);
        alert.SetTitle("Actualizar/Eliminar");
        alert.SetView(et);

        alert.SetPositiveButton("Actualizar ", (senderAlert, args) =>
        {

        });

        alert.SetNegativeButton("Eliminar", (senderAlert, args) =>
        {

        });

        RunOnUiThread(() =>
        {
            alert.Show();
        });
    }
```

Comment: un gusto en ayudarte. :D